# sqlserver merge statement 100+ columns

Tags: sql-server

Im trying to merge 2 tables in SQLServer,

Here are the tables,

```
Table_1

ID NAME  SALARY
1  MIKE  5000
2  BRIAN 6000
3  RAM   8000

Table_2

ID NAME  AGE
1  MIKE  50
2  BRIAN 20
3  RAM   30

RESULT
ID NAME  SALARY AGE
1  MIKE  5000   50
2  BRIAN 6000   20
3  RAM   8000   30
```

I tried left outer join,

```
SELECT TB1.ID, TB1.NAME, TB1.SALARY, TB2.AGE FROM TABLE_1 TB1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
TABLE_2 TB2
ON TB1.ID = TB2.ID
```

This expects as expected but the actual tables I will be using will have 300 columns in table_1 and 250 columns in table_2,

I need all table_1 & table_2 matching columns, missing table_1 columns and missing table_2 columns.

Answer (score 0):

You need full outer join:

```
SELECT TB1.*, TB2.*
FROM TABLE_1 TB1 FULL OUTER JOIN TABLE_2 TB2 ON TB1.ID = TB2.ID
```

http://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/perform-a-full-outer-join.php

This will give all the columns and rows from both the tables. In case you just need matching rows and all the columns you can use left outer join or inner join as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

The following will give you a third table from specified two table

```
Declare @Sql1 varchar(MAX) -- if you are using SQL server 2000 then @Sql1 varchar(8000)
Declare @Sql2 varchar(MAX) -- if you are using SQL server 2000 then @Sql2 varchar(8000)

Set @Sql1 = ''

SELECT @Sql1 = @Sql1 + 'Table_1.' + c.name + ','
FROM sys.columns c
    JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE t.name = 'Table_1'

SELECT @Sql1 = @Sql1 + 'Table_2.' + c.name + ','
FROM sys.columns c
    JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE t.name = 'Table_2'
and c.name <> 'ID'

Set @Sql1 = LEFT(@Sql1, (Len(@Sql1) - 1))
Print @Sql1

Set @Sql2 = 'Select ' + @Sql1 + ' Into RESULT From ' + ' Table_1 , Table_2 where Table_1.ID = Table_2.ID'

-- Set @Sql2 = 'Insert into RESULT( ' + @Sql1 + ')'
-- Set @Sql2 = @Sql2 + ' Select ' + @Sql1 + ' from ETProgram , Table_2 where ETProgram.ID = Table_2.ID'

Print @Sql2
```